# Why does adding an HTTP Interceptor cause CORS errors?

Tags: angular, cors, interceptor

I'm developing a Angular 6 app with a PHP REST Api. My dev environment is hosted on my localhost so to begin I've had to enable the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to bypass any CORS errors I was getting.

Recently I've been trying to implement JWT with an interceptor to add them to my HTTP requests. As soon as I enabled the interpreter following examples from google, I started getting the CORS error again:

```
blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
```

I'm positive it has to do with my interceptor because when I comment it out, it works again. Here is the code for the interceptor that I would like to get working:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/index';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
         'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        // 'Accept'       : 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

I have even attempted to strip it down to just set the Authorization header to avail.

If I comment out the Authorization header and just leave the Content-Type, I still get the CORS error. If I change the Content-type to plain/text, it works but then I don't have the authorization header. If I keep the content type to plain/text and add the Authorization header, I get the CORS error.

At this point I just want to see the authorization header in the $_SERVER var so the PHP is pretty simple to test:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, 
OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Access, Origin, 
Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 0
        ,'message'=> $_SERVER
    ));

exit;
```

Here is my app module to show the interceptor is configured:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginFormComponent } from './login-form/login-form.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthInterceptor} from './auth.interceptor';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginFormComponent,
    MessagesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here is the login service that I'm using to send the HTTP request:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ServerResponse } from './server-response';
import {MessagesService} from './messages.service';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private ms: MessagesService,
              private auth: AuthService) { }
  login(formData) {
    this.ms.clear();
    console.log('JSON data', JSON.stringify((formData)));
    console.log(this.auth.getToken());
    return this.http.post('http://jpapp.com/api/login/login.php',     JSON.stringify(formData))
      .subscribe((rs: ServerResponse) => {
        console.log('%cPost Success', 'color: green;');
        console.log(rs);
    }, (error) => ({status: -99, message: error}));
  }
}
```

If I remove the interceptor, the Requet header looks like this (which is where I got the idea to try changing the content-type to plain/text):

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: text/plain
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

And when I have the interceptor enabled the Request header looks like this:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

I have read that I may be able to bypass this with a chrome extension but wanted to know if there was something in my code first before installing extensions to try.

Any info is appreciated!

Comment: What if you just send in empty object? `req = req.clone()`, do you still get CORS?

Comment: if I just send an empty object I do not get the the CORS error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update

**edit**: I should mention the reason why setting the req.clone() to blank works that I found out is because the preflight only happens on *complex* as opposed to *simple* cors requests. As soon as you add a custom header, in my case Authorization or do anything that causes it to no longer be a simple request it, by default, sends the preflight request with the OPTIONS method instead of, in my case, POST. This article does a great job of explaining cors and a simple vs complex request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

The preflight response error had nothing to do with the code itself. The issue was with the configuration of my IIS 10 web server.

Following this article: [CORS Module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference) I added the required cors nodes to my web.config file and now it is working correctly

<strike>I was able to bypass the preflight request CORS error by installing the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * Chrome extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en</strike>

It seems to still only work if I keep the default URL matching `*://*/*` if I change it to match my URLs I get the CORS error again but that might just be an issue with my pattern matching. It would be nice if there was an explanation to how it works.

I'm still looking for a reason as to why passing the authorization via an interceptor breaks the servers Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * as I'm sure I will come across the issue again once I actually deploy this app and api. It's also a PITA to use this extension with the default configuration since it will break a bunch of sites.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem to get the token in the login, and I solved by adding an if-else in the interceptor request

```
   const yourToken = this.auth.getToken();

    if (yourToken) {
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${yourToken}`
            }
        });
    } else {
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                Accept: 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }

    return next.handle(req);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by also checking of my custom header exists in the request, I noticed the error whenever I added headers to the get request and works fine without the headers. So I did this instead
`if (!(req.headers.get('No-auth')) || ((req.headers.get('No-auth') === 'True') && (req.headers.get('TokenRefresh') === 'False')))enter code here { return next.handle(req.clone());}`
if no custom header is in the request, it means a header wasn't provided, in so doing, it just clones the original request.