# Angular/Typescript: Interceptor makes the browser sent an additional OPTIONS http request

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-http-interceptors

I am using an interceptor in order to add a JWT token to each request sent to the backend as described [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/#howtobuildanauthenticationhttpinterceptor). The way I include the interceptor in the `app.module.ts` file is

```
providers: [
    ...
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
]
```

When I examine the network tab on my browser I see an additional `OPTIONS` request instead of the `GET` request I was initially sending.

[image]

If I don't use the interceptor, the `OPTIONS` request does not get sent. Why is this happening, and can I keep the interceptor but get rid of the additional `OPTIONS` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54544082/5589918)

> As soon as you add a custom header, in my case Authorization or do anything that causes it to no longer be a simple request it, by default, sends the preflight request with the OPTIONS method instead of, in my case, POST.

It is also mentioned in more detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests).

So you can't avoid the additional request if you add custom headers to it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the interceptor that's doing this. It's called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

Everybrowser is sending a OPTIONS request to domains that are different that the one hosting the page.

Comment: But why does it not get sent when I don't use the interceptor?

Comment: Check the answer I added

Comment: Nice to learn, thanks for sharing it !